# Sitecore Azure deployment error-CreateDataBaseServer

Tags: azure, sitecore, sitecore-azure

I'm trying to deploy my Sitecore website using Sitecore Azure module and getting below error. The error says it `40652 Cannot move or create server.`, but I need to use the existing database. But Sitecore Azure module not asking to use existing one or create new DB.

```
27/06/2017, 16:55:04 [S] Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer failed System.ApplicationException:  [S] Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer failed ---> System.ApplicationException: Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer is failed ---> Sitecore.Azure.Exceptions.ManagementApiRequestException: REST REQUEST FAILED : Request: https://management.core.windows.net:8443/2aeb5798-c598-439c-84d7-648aeb832b5a/services/sqlservers/servers Server response = 40652 Cannot move or create server. Subscription 'ABC' will exceed server quota. 16 1 ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request.
 at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
 at Sitecore.Azure.Managers.HttpGatewayManager.GetHttpResponse(String uri, String httpMethod, String versionXMsVersion, String body)

 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

 at Sitecore.Azure.Managers.HttpGatewayManager.GetHttpResponse(String uri, String httpMethod, String versionXMsVersion, String body)
 at Sitecore.Azure.Providers.AzureSQL.AzureSqlProvider.CreateDataBaseServer(String subscriptionID, String location, String userID, String password)
 at Sitecore.Azure.Managers.AzureManagers.AzureSqlManager.CreateDataBaseServer(String subscriptionID, AzureSqlDatabase database, String login, String password)
 at Sitecore.Azure.Managers.AzureManagers.AzureSqlManager.CreateDataBaseServer(AzureSqlDatabase azureSqlDatabase, String login, String password)
 at Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer.ResolveServer(AzureSqlDatabase azureSqlDb, List`1 resolvedServers, Dictionary`2 preferServer) 
at Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.Automation.Azure.SqlAzureDatabaseServer.Action(RolePipelineArgsBase args)
 at Sitecore.Azure.Pipelines.BasePipeline.RolePipelineProcessor.Process(RolePipelineArgsBase args)
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
 --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As the error states: 'Cannot move or create server. Subscription XXX will exceed quota'.

According to the table on [Microsoft's Azure Subscription limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-subscription-service-limits) it seems that there's a default number of SQL Database Servers of 6. When you try and create more you'll hit this particular error. 
 It seems like you can simply raise the limit by raising a support query. Quoting from the linked-to page:

> If you want to raise the limit or quota above the Default Limit, open
>   an online customer support request at no charge. The limits can't be
>   raised above the Maximum Limit value shown in the following tables. If
>   there is no Maximum Limit column, then the resource doesn't have
>   adjustable limits.

Answer (score 0):

> ... but I need to use the existing database.

The module hasn't been designed to use an existent Azure SQL Server nor Azure SQL Databases. However, you can try the following trick: https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/001970

**NB:** Sitecore has retired the module since Sitecore XP 8.2 Update-1 release. Therefore, I would recommend start looking into a new approach for deploying Sitecore solution to Azure. See here for details: https://doc.sitecore.net/cloud